# Select new or updated records com table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

It's possible to get all the new or update records from one table in postgresql by 
specified date?

something like this:

Select NEW OR UPDATED FROM anyTable WHERE dt_insert or dt_update = '2015-01-01'

tks

Comment: put an auto-updating timestamp on the tables, then it's just `where autoupdatefield >= $oldest_time_you_want`

Comment: Not clear, pleas be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if you added a trigger-maintained field that keeps track of the last change time.

There is no internal row timestamp in PostgreSQL, so in the absence of a trigger-maintained timestamp for the row, there's no way to find rows changed/added after a certain time.

---

PostgreSQL *does* have internal information on the transaction ID that wrote a row, stored in the `xmin` hidden column. There's no record of what transaction ID committed when, though, until PostgreSQL 9.5 which keeps track of this if and only if the new `track_commit_timestamps` setting is turned on. Additionally, PostgreSQL eventually clears the creator transaction ID information from a tuple because it re-uses transaction IDs, so it only works for fairly recent transactions.

In other words: it's kind-of possible in a rough way, if you understand the innards of the database, but should really only be used for forensic and recovery purposes.